# How do I amplify the volume of Windows?

Tags: windows-7, audio

In my laptop, some YouTube videos have a too low volume to hear anything. I'm forced to download the video and play it in MPlayer where I can use -softvol to increate the volume.

Is there any software that can amplify Windows audio globally? Similar to how -softvol works on MPlayer but for all applications.

I'm using Windows 7, my sound card doesn't have any additional user interface apart from what Windows shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Loudness Equalization. In certain situations it can appear to increase volume by raising the volume of relatively quiet sounds. Enable it like this:

- Control Panel -> Sound
- Right-click speakers and select Properties
- Select 3rd tab **Enhancements** and in that window select Loudness Equalization (More info in the link above).

This procedure does not seem to make the loudest sound any louder.

Comment: I couldn't hear any difference. Also the link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

You could install [Equalizer APO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/), the Configurator will open automatically select the sound device for which to apply it (Mine is Speakers/Headphones IDT High definition CODEC).

If you have no sound after the installation, open the Configurator again, select Troubleshooting options and remove both "Use original APO" tick boxes.

Now you can open the Editor and boost the sound of the preamp.

I usually leave the EQ, and preamp off and only enable the preamp when the clip I'm trying to hear is very soft. I don't think you should have this always on, because if something is already load it will just lead to clipping (distortion).

Comment: I tried. It's overcomplicated. I could not make it work. Uninstalled it.

Comment: finally some good open source software which boosts the "digital" windows volume and works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You could also right click on the speaker icon and Volume Mixer to make sure that your browser's volume is not turned down.  Sometimes Windows has a habit of adjusting the volume of things for you (each program that has sound has its own independent volume control).

Comment: Ha! I was looking for some obscure solution,  deep in the Windows internals, when my solution was simply this.